# Macro language equivalent to "Image > Adjust > Brightness/Contrast... > Apply"

Tags: imagej, imagej-macro

I am trying to write an ImageJ macro and need to duplicate what happens when you use

> Image > Adjust > Brightness/Contrast... > Apply

on an image that is neither 8-bit nor RGB. I have tested with a 16-bit grayscale and confirmed that doing so using the GUI does, in fact, change the pixel values. However, when I try to use the commands listed in the recorder, it gives me an error message, stating the supposed limitations as described in the [documentation](http://imagejdocu.tudor.lu/doku.php?id=gui:image:adjust). This is true for both the macro language (`run("Apply LUT")`) and Java (`IJ.run(imp, "Apply LUT", "")`).

Is the output of the recorder incorrect, am I missing something else, or is it a bug that this works using the GUI?

Comment: Could you please bring this issue up in the [ImageJ forum](http://forum.imagej.net/)? That's the place where 1) the developers will read it and 2) other ImageJ users are more likely to find this information in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was not aware of the forum.